# Restrict service to only be singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

Is there any way to make a service *only* usable as as singleton in ASP.NET? Or vice versa, not allow it to be used as a singleton?

```cs
services.AddSingleton<ISingletonOnlyService, SingletonOnlyService>(); // This should work
services.AddTransient<ISingletonOnlyService, SingletonOnlyService>(); // This should throw an error
services.AddScoped<ISingletonOnlyService, SingletonOnlyService>(); // This should throw an error
```

Or,

```cs
services.AddSingleton<INotSingletonService, NotSingletonService>(); // This should throw an error
services.AddTransient<INotSingletonService, NotSingletonService>(); // This should work
services.AddScoped<INotSingletonService, NotSingletonService>(); // This should work
```

Comment: It is possible with service.AddYourOwnSingleton

Comment: You can write a Roslyn analyzer to show warnings or even compilation errors. You can create a special interface, say IOnlyRegistersAsSingleton, and make the Roslyn analyzer show a compilation error when `AddTransient` or `AddScoped` are used with a class that implements this marker interface. I am not sure if this is worth it though.